# Get a collection and add a value to the response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I want to create in the Server script a function that can return a collection plus some extra value. 
For example:

```
Meteor.publish("users", function () {
    var users;
    users = Meteor.users.find();
    users.forEach(function (user){
        user.profile.image = "some-url";
    });
    return users;
});
```

But this don't work proper. **My question is**: What is the right way to add a value to a collection reponse in a publish function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this important to do with the server? You could use the transform function on the client:

**Client JS**

```
//Somewhere where it can run before anything else (make sure you have access to the other bits of the document i.e services.facebook.id otherwise you'll get a services is undefined 

Meteor.users._transform = function(doc) {
    doc.profile.image = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + doc.services.facebook.id + "/picture";
    return doc;
}
```

Now when you do:

```
Meteor.user().profile.image
=> "http://graph.facebook.com/55592/picture"
```

I have opened an issue before with regards to sharing a transform onto the client: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/821

Comment: Thanks @Akshat! Where I can find more information about the `_transform` method?

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.meteor.com/#collections, theres an example slightly further down. The _transform I used above is undocumented but it allows the same use as on the docs for a users collection

Comment: I'm sorry but I couldn't make this works, I can't see any changes on my `Meteor.user().profile`

Comment: OK could you check your JS Console for any errors? If you typed in `Meteor.user().services.facebook.id` in your browser console do you get anything? Also where are you running the transform? It needs to be run before you call any user data

Comment: Im not using any services, just the account_password. I don't have any error on the console and I run this immediately after the  `Meteor.autorun(function () {Meteor.subscribe("users"); });`

Comment: Lets do this from scratch, so in Meteor.startup() on the client, you need all those subscription functions as well as the transform I used above. Instead of the `"http://graph.facebook.com/" + doc.services.facebook.id + "/picture";` use whatever you want as the profile pic URL for that person. Meteor.autorun (now Deps.autorun) is to be used when you with a subscription when it has a variable that you want to change using reactivity.

Comment: After various test, in the only place that transform option works was in:
`Template.aside.user_list = function () {
 var users = Meteor.users.find({
  _id: {
   $not: Meteor.userId()
  }
 }, {
  transform: function (user) {
   user.profile.name = "ASDDSA";
   return user;
  }
 });
 return users;
};`

Comment: The `$not` use case is different I think you mean `$ne` there. So you want everyone else's profile to be transformed except the current user? If I could see the place you've put transform perhaps I could be of some help with why the other way doesn't work. If this way works its also all well & fine

Comment: I wrote an issue in the meteor repository to find out if there's a bug here.- 
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/885 
Thanks @Akshat! You can look at the code there, the $not is not necesary in this case.

Comment: By the way, I saw your issue on the repository but it doesn't seem to have a clear answer

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 ways you can implement a publish function:

1. By returning a cursor (or an array of cursors)
2. By using this.added(), this.changed() and this.removed().

Only method 2 allows to modify returned documents.

Please refer to Meteor documentation [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish). However, since the provided sample code might look complex, here is another one:

```
// server: publish the rooms collection
Meteor.publish("rooms", function () {
  return Rooms.find({});
});
```

is equivalent to:

```
// server: publish the rooms collection
Meteor.publish("rooms", function () {
  var self = this;
  var handle = Rooms.find({}).observeChanges({
    added:   function(id, fields) { self.added("rooms", id, fields); },
    changed: function(id, fields) { self.changed("rooms", id, fields); },
    removed: function(id)         { self.added("rooms", id); },
    }
  });
  self.ready();
  self.onStop(function () { handle.stop(); });
});
```

In the second sample, you can modify the 'field' parameter before sending it for publication, like this:

```
added: function(id, fields) { 
    fields.newField = 12;
    self.added("rooms", id, fields); 
},
```

Source: [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/meteor-talk/EgOPlR8ilZo/V-XvMRg0xDUJ).