# Transforming on excluded field in meteor Mongo Collection

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

```
Meteor.publish("thing", function(options) {

    return Collection.find({}, {fields: {anArray: 0}})
})
```

I exclude "anArray" because it contains userids not meant to be seen by each user. However it could contain the logged in user itself, in which case the user needs to know it.

```
Collection = new Mongo.Collection("thing", {
    transform: function(document) {

        _.each(document.anArray, function(item) {

            item = true
        })

        return document
    }
})
```

Above I try to transform the collection(simplified) but because the "anArray" is excluded, "anArray" is simply not defined.

How can I let the user know he is in "anArray" without compromising all other users in "anArray"? (I tried to do that in the transform.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package I developed, [meteor-middleware](https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-middleware). It provides a nice pluggable API for this. So instead of just providing a transform, you can stack them one on another. This allows for code reuse, permissions checks (like removing or aggregating fields based on permissions), etc.

For example, for your particular problem, you could do (in CoffeeScript):

```
thing = new PublishEndpoint 'thing', (options) ->
  Collection.find {}

class HideAnArrayMiddleware
  added: (publish, collection, id, fields) =>
    fields.anArray = _.intersection fields.anArray, [publish.userId] if fields.anArray
    publish.added collection, id, fields

  changed: (publish, collection, id, fields) =>
    fields.anArray = _.intersection fields.anArray, [publish.userId] if fields.anArray
    publish.changed collection, id, fields

thing.use new HideAnArrayMiddleware()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to include or exclude elements of an array, so your best bet is to define an explicit Boolean field in the document for the user being in the array.

Also, because transforms on the server are ignored (please vote for [this issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/821)), you'll have to set that field in the database if it's dynamically computed. Similar SO questions:  [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093560/meteor-collection-transform-is-it-done-on-the-server-or-on-the-client-or-it-de), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20895913/1269037), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343534/how-to-publish-a-view-transform-of-a-collection-in-meteor).

An alternative is to define a non-database-backed collection. Have a look at the [counts-by-room example](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish).

Answer (score 0):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28392390/3567351), here is how you access document fields before publishing them:

```
// server: publish the rooms collection
Meteor.publish("rooms", function () {
  var self = this;
  var handle = Rooms.find({}).observeChanges({
    added:   function(id, fields) { self.added("rooms", id, fields); },
    changed: function(id, fields) { self.changed("rooms", id, fields); },
    removed: function(id)         { self.added("rooms", id); },
    }
  });
  self.ready();
  self.onStop(function () { handle.stop(); });
});
```

In your case, maybe you can do something like this:

```
added: function(id, fields) { 
    if (fields.anArray)
        if (fields.anArray.indexOf(self.userId) !== -1)
            fields.anArray = [self.userId];
        else
            delete fields.anArray;
    self.added("rooms", id, fields); 
},
```

You'll also have to take care of the `changed` function in a similar way.